# UICollectionView takes a long time to refresh data

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, reloaddata

here's a challenge for you all...

I have an `UICollectionView` inside my `UIViewController` witch is loading correctly. 
I also have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class witch contains an `UIButton`.

I retrieve a `NSArray` from my server with some `UIImage` objects in order to assign one background image to the button of my custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

Here's the code of my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UserPhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"userPhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [[cell imageButton] setBackgroundImage:[userPublicImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [[cell imageButton] setBackgroundImage:[userPrivateImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see is quite simple.

Here comes the strange behavior: if I put all my custom `UICollectionViewCell` in just one section of the `UICollectionView`, the performance is okay...

any ideas?

Some extra information: The `UICollectionView` have headers. Custom headers. Just an `UIView` wit an `UILabel` at this moment.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableView = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"collectionHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [headerView frame].size.width, 40.0f)];
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            [titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedStringFromTable (@"collectionTitle_publicPhotos", [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] , @"")];
        } else {
            [titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedStringFromTable (@"collectionTitle_privatePhotos", [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] , @"")];
        }
        [headerView addSubview:titleLabel];

        reusableView = headerView;
    }

    return reusableView;
}
```

Comment: You should use Instruments and the Time Profiler to identify where the time is being spent.

Comment: Well, Time Profiler says that the problem is here : UserPhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"userPhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];... The reusableCell... maybe I should include "if ( cell == nil )"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. For some strange reason, the `[collectionView reloadData]` was not being fired on main thread. So, my solution is as simple as that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_collectionUserPhotos reloadData];
    });
```

Now the, UICollectionView updates immediately, as desired.

Some notes: this `[collectionView reloadData]` was called in a delegate method from a custom class using [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com), after using queues. Hope it helps.